# wmic is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt, wmic

I'm trying to get my motherboard's serial number through the following command in windows 10 cmd:

```
wmic baseboard get serialnumber
```

but I receive this Error:

```
wmic is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

while, this command works on other systems of mine (for example my office pc). What may be wrong with it?

Comment: Thank you. In my case the current directory is different to the directory containing the file to execute. So first of all I have to change the directory by this command: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wbem and then run wmic command in cmd.

Comment: Note: `wmic baseboard get serialnumber` gets the serial number of your systemboard, while `wmic bios get serialnumber` gets the serial number of your system. They are not the same, so chose carefully which one to use.

Comment: Actually I'm using this cmd command in a script as a username. So I'm better to keep it here to help others who may have the same problem in their scripts. I recommend to use cd command in the script before using wmic, as wmic directory may not be the default directory.

Comment: in case you guys wonder why you get this error in windows 10 / 11, its because microsoft have removed wmic in their latest windows update. reference: https://winaero.com/microsoft-removed-the-wmic-tool-from-windows-11-dev-builds/

Answer (score 2):

In my case the current directory is different to the directory containing the file to execute. So first of all I have to change the directory by this command: `cd C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wbem` and then run wmic command in cmd.

Comment: `wmic.exe` should be within your `%path%`. If it's not, your `%path%` variable is messed up, and you will have more problems.

Comment: Could you help me how to change cmd current directory through python script?

Comment: Fix your `PATH` variable in the system environment-variable editor. It should start with `%SystemRoot%\System32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem`. Also, in a script you shouldn't rely on the working directory being implicitly in `PATH`. Windows [can be configured](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-needcurrentdirectoryforexepathw) to prevent implicit inclusion of "." in the search path that's used by CMD and `CreateProcess`.